# Android: Requesting external images based on DPI

Tags: android, image, resolution, dpi

When you've got bundled graphical assets you place them in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc. so the right image is loaded based on the device's DPI.

What's the norm when dealing with external images requested from the web?

The solution I have in mind is to define the URL in resource folders using configuration qualifiers. Eg.

```
values-ldpi
-- http://website.com/logo24x24.jpg
values-mdpi
-- http://website.com/logo32x32.jpg
values-hdpi
-- http://website.com/logo48x48.jpg
values-xhdpi
-- http://website.com/logo64x64.jpg
```

Then in the layout XML define the image as being 32x32dp.

What's the common way of doing this? Doing it programmatically rather than using config qualifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability to run a servlet (or any server side logic) it would be best to send the DPI as a parameter and make the decisions on the filenames on the server.
This will allow for easier changes without the need of updating the client and also will ease the process of writing a long list of values in the client.

Comment: Thanks. I opted for static graphics at each of the main density groups (120,160,240,320). I'll probably write an htaccess rule to default to hdpi should there be an unrecognised density. I'm treating tvdpi as hdpi. File naming looks like: image_32dpx32dp_240dpi.png would be 48px by 48px.

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = display.getWidth();  


                URL url = null;

                if (width < 360) {
                    url = new URL(start + "source/images/thumbnails/mid/" + urls.get(i));
                } else if (width < 1280) {
                    url = new URL(start + "source/images/thumbnails/big/" + urls.get(i));
                } else if (width < 1920){
                    url = new URL(start + "source/images/" + urls.get(i));
                }
```

It is based on own opinion, u could use different sizes